# Declaring variable to SELECT INTO in a function

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

How do i declare a variable to select into in SQL-DEVELOPER

this is not working and i don't what the workaround would be

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION CORRESPONDING_DATE 
(
  DATE_IN IN VARCHAR
)

 RETURN  VARCHAR is out_date VARCHAR(250);
 tmp_current_yr_hday_start DATE;
 BEGIN
   DECLARE    
   SELECT hday_start into tmp_current_yr_hday_start from hday_period where year = TO_CHAR(DATE_IN, 'YYYY'); -- get the current year holiday start period date            
  RETURN (out_date);
END CORRESPONDING_DATE;
```

Error messages are

> Error(11,3): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
>
> Error(11,26): PLS-00201: identifier 'TMP_CURRENT_YR_HDAY_START' must
>   be declared
>
> Error(11,52): PL/SQL: ORA-00904: : invalid identifier

Comment: yeah that wrong copy paste i have updated, still wont work

Comment: 1) You do not need the `DECLARE` statement, it's implied in your function, 2) You are not populating `out_date` anywhere so there is nothing to return, 3) `out_date` and `tmp_current_yr_hday_start` have different data types - although I'm not sure if those are related or not.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can remember, PLSQL fonctions blocks have following structures:

- DECLARE
- BEGIN
- END

Can you try:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION CORRESPONDING_DATE 
(
  DATE_IN IN VARCHAR
)
RETURN  VARCHAR is 
    out_date VARCHAR(250);
    tmp_current_yr_hday_start DATE;
BEGIN
  SELECT hday_start into tmp_current_yr_hday_start from hday_period where year = TO_CHAR(DATE_IN, 'YYYY'); -- get the current year holiday start period date
  -- WARN nothing is set in out_date... 
  RETURN (out_date);
END CORRESPONDING_DATE;
/
```

I cannot test though. I don't have access to an Oracle Server right now.

Comment: I'm getting a host of errors with this Error(6,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "DECLARE" when expecting one of the following:     begin function pragma procedure subtype type <an identifier>    <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> current cursor delete    exists prior external language The symbol "begin" was substituted for "DECLARE" to continue.

Comment: and this                                                                                                            Error(13,23): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:     ( begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod    null pragma raise return select update while with    <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>    <a bind variable> << continue close current delete fetch lock    insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall    merge pipe purge

Comment: I just edited the snippet. Stand alone function declaration is different from function in packages. The declare section does not begin with DECLARE keyword.